# Retrieving DOM values after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, perl, dom

I want to check some DOM values from Perl (I don't want to use browser and debugger manually).

These DOM values are loaded after an AJAX call, and the sample function for one of these values would be:

```
<script language="javascript">
    try {   
        var openValue = FComma(fnRound(Symbol[24],2));
        if (openValue == "0.00") document.write('n/a');
        else document.write(openValue);

    } catch (exception) {}
</script>
```

I can't get it directly from AJAX. I'm wondering if there is any possibility to grab the DOM values after the AJAX call was done. This call is done only at the beginning.

Comment: Are you sure it's an ajax call? Because doing document.write after the page have loaded will blow up the page and ajax calls generally only return after the page have loaded (since it's async and all). You're probably doing non ajax things and call it ajax since you don't understand what ajax means.

Comment: I mean this page: nyse.com/about/listed/lcddata.html?ticker=RDSB . I want to check the value for "NYSE Only Close".

Answer (score 0):

What I would do (er, try, because I'm not certain this will do what you want) is: use Firefox with the Web Developer add-on installed. After the page has loaded and the AJAX stuff has finished, go to Web Developer's View Source menu and choose View Generated Source; copy/paste the source into your editor and/or Perl script, and do what you want to do with it.

Comment: I'd like to use script only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [WWW::Scripter](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aScripter):

```
use WWW::Scripter;
$w = new WWW::Scripter;
 
$w->use_plugin('Ajax');  # packaged separately
 
$w->get('http://some.site.com/that/relies/on/ajax');
$w->eval(' alert("Hello from JavaScript") ');
$w->document->getElementsByTagName('div')->[0]->....
 
$w->content; # returns the HTML content, possibly modified
             # by scripts
```